# How to close form and open another

Tags: c#

Currently learning to code in C#. I have used the code

```
Form1.Hide();
Music_Menu.Show();
```

The names for the forms are correct and believe this should work but I get this error when I hover over the text:

> an object reference is required to access non static field member or
>   property c#

Comment: `Form1 form1 = new Form1(); form1.Hide();` You need `instance` of the type to access non-static members

Comment: you must create the object, after you can use the method of object. C# is not similar to VB.Net : `Form1 form1 = new Form1(); Music_Menu music_Menu= new Music_Menu();`

Answer (score 1):

I am betting that Music_Menu is the name of your form's class.

You need to create an INSTANCE of the form.  VB did this "behind the scenes," but C# demands you get it right.

Somewhere in Program.Main(), I'll bet you have a line:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

You need to keep that reference.  A private static field in the Program class should work.

```
private static Form1 _myForm1;
private static Music_Menu _myMusic_Menu;
```

Then in the Main() method, change that to:

```
_myForm1 = new Form1();
Application.Run(_myForm1);
```

Then your code (where you switch) should be (in Program.cs):

```
_myForm1.Hide(); 
_myMusic_Menu = new Music_Menu();
_myMusic_Menu.Show();
```

Alternatively, if you want to run the code in Form1 (and assuming you want to come back to your instance of Form1:

```
this.Hide();
var myMusic_Menu = new Music_Menu();
myMusic.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

You'll probably have some scope issues to straighten out depending on your context, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: You have an unnecessary space here  _myMusic_Menu .Show();

Comment: Yeah, spacing is getting mangled somewhere.  It'll compile.  I seem to have to clean up code samples 2 or 3 times before SE accepts it as written.  I see another "missing" space in assigning _myForm1.  VS will still compile it, and you can clean it up easily.  I'll try to edit, *AGAIN*.  :)